# Select multiple years in separate columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table that stores the date and price of purchases.

For example

```
date       | price
---------------------
2014-1-12  | 6.50
2014-2-34  | 10.99
2015-1-01  | 3.22
2015-2-14  | 4.12
```

And so on.

What I want to achieve: A query that outputs the SUM of the purchases grouped per month of the year.

The IMPORTANT thing is, though, that I need to have the different years in COLUMNS to be able to make a graph with a separate line for each year. So the output I need is this:

```
MONTH | 2014    |  2015 
JAN   |  123.23 |  99.1
FEB   |  457.00 |  122.00
MAR   |  299.99 |  789.12
...   |
NOV   |  333.33 | 10.99
DEC   |  100.00 | 20.10
```

Is this even possible? I searched quite a long time for things like "year on year" query etc. But I could not find anything.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: See if this is similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Comment: I might not have time to put a solution together, but I wanted to make a few comments. First, your query would be "breakable" in a plain select statement because you can't (without using dialect specific pivots) use a simple function to dynamically add columns as the years go by. Are you okay manually changing this each year? As an alternative, it would be relatively trivial to write a query that groups by year and month (with a case statement to change it to text) and then format this on the application side. Are you open to some application-side code? Which language?

Comment: It will be simple if you expect to have columns for "current year", "year - 1", "year - 2"... i.e. relative to current date.

Comment: Palu: I would be open to server side code, but you already directed me in the right direction.

Comment: To my way of thinking, problems of data display should always be resolved in presentation layer code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select monthname(date) as mon,
       sum(case when year(date) = 2014 then price else 0 end) as price_2014,
       sum(case when year(date) = 2015 then price else 0 end) as price_2015
from table t
group by monthname(date)
order by max(month(date));
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I need. Only thing I need to do now is to add a new case for the years to come - easy.